# MSM multisite Front End login Site B members not access SITE A any section

Tags: multi-site-manager, freemember

We have Facing Problem While MSM two Different primary & secondary Front End Login .

Problem: We have Created member group for secondary site (site B) members Register SITE B member in that group but When We have same user logged in primary site front end login (Site A) then its logged in successfully and site B member access all SITE A section.

above our Problem , We need to both Site front end login different , it means SITE B member group not access SITE A login after login any section.

let me know if you have any idea for this.

Thanks,
ZW PD

Answer (score 0):

In ExpressionEngine MSM member groups are installation wide.
For restricting SITE B members to access content of SITE A follow steps:

```
1) Create a template/snippet/header
2) Include this template/snippet/header in every template of SITE A
3) Check current logged in user member group.
4) If member group from SITE B then destroy the user session and redirect to home page with message "You are not authorized to access SITE A"
```